# Clone an HTML Row without previous entered text

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have the following HTML and JAVASCRIPT code. Right now, I can dynamically add rows but it also clones the data already entered. How can I clone it with the textfields being blank? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div align="center" id="border">
<p>
<div id="rebate_400p">
<strong>400P</strong><br>
</div>

<table id="tables" cellspacing="5">
    <tr align="center" id="table_titles">
        <td>Tier</td>
        <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
        <td>Multiplier</td>
        <td>UOM</td>
        <td>Retro</td>
        <td>Guaranteed</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" name="tier">1</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="purchase_minimum"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="multiplier"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="uom"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="retro"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="guaranteed"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="paid"></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="delRow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="addmoreRowsbutton" value="Add row" onclick="insRow()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</p>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode;
    i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
}

function insRow()
{

    console.log( 'hi');
    var x=document.getElementById('tables');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    x.appendChild(new_row)
}
```

Comment: Not exactly related, but the counter for the new ids doesn't work when you first remove row(s) from the table, and then add a new row. Declare the counter in the outer scope, and increment that on every use. Doesn't your code create blank inputs already? You could do that in a loop, though.

Comment: It creates empty inputs if you enter data into the 2nd row, 3rd row, and so on. However, if you add data into the first row and hit "add row" then the data will get copied to the following rows.

Comment: Just a second, I'll create a fiddle ...

Comment: [Like so](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp4jpscz/)

Comment: Perfect works great!!

Comment: [An updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp4jpscz/1/), which updates the first column. Notice, that this will work only in browsers supporting ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `querySelectorAll` to get all inputs with type text then loop through them and edit the value ::

```js
function deleteRow(row)
{
  var i=row.parentNode.parentNode;
  i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
}

function insRow()
{

  console.log( 'hi');
  var x=document.getElementById('tables');
  var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = x.rows.length;
  new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

  var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';
  
  var inputs = new_row.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
  
  for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
    inputs[i].value='';
  
  
  x.appendChild(new_row)
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="border">
  <p>
  <div id="rebate_400p">
    <strong>400P</strong><br>
  </div>

  <table id="tables" cellspacing="5">
    <tr align="center" id="table_titles">
      <td>Tier</td>
      <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
      <td>Multiplier</td>
      <td>UOM</td>
      <td>Retro</td>
      <td>Guaranteed</td>
      <td>Paid</td>
      <td>Delete?</td>
      <td>Add Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" name="tier">1</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="purchase_minimum"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="multiplier"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="uom"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="retro"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="guaranteed"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="paid"></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="delRow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="addmoreRowsbutton" value="Add row" onclick="insRow()"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode;
    i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
}

function insRow()
{
    var x=document.getElementById('tables');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    
    Array.prototype.slice.call(
          new_row.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'))
          .forEach(function (el) {
            el.value = '';
        });

    x.appendChild(new_row)
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="border">
<p>
<div id="rebate_400p">
<strong>400P</strong><br>
</div>

<table id="tables" cellspacing="5">
    <tr align="center" id="table_titles">
        <td>Tier</td>
        <td>Purchase Minimum</td>
        <td>Multiplier</td>
        <td>UOM</td>
        <td>Retro</td>
        <td>Guaranteed</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" name="tier">1</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="purchase_minimum"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="multiplier"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="uom"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="retro"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="guaranteed"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rebate_tables" name="paid"></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="delRow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="addmoreRowsbutton" value="Add row" onclick="insRow()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</p>
```